# Вставка значений в mssql таблицу через php

Tags: php, sql-server

Подскажите синтаксис что-бы вставить значение в таблицу
 
простая таблица
нужно вставить в нее значение переменной

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO Pcontent ([Ptittle])VALUES('$Ptittle')" ; echo "<br>";
```

но в таблицу ничего не заносится

вот листинг:

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO dbo.Pcontent ([Ptittle])VALUES('$Ptittle')" ; echo "<br>";
$result = sql_query($sql)or die('Error querying MSSQL database');
```

при sql query
появляется ошибка:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sql_query() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\technet\admin\scripts\gen_page.php:51
Stack trace:

#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\technet\admin\scripts\gen_page.php on line 51
```

Comment: зачем Вам `echo "<br>";` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO TABLENAME  (id,name) VALUES ('$id','$name')";
$result = mssql_query($query,$dbc)
```

`$query` - запрос
`$dbc` - подключение к БД

Comment: крашится с таким выводом   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mssql_query() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\technet\admin\scripts\gen_page.php:51
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\technet\admin\scripts\gen_page.php on line 51

Comment: @qazqaz, http://stackoverflow.com/a/17103976/4827341

Answer (score 0):

разобрался, надо было использовать вместо mssql ssqlsrv

Comment: Это не ответ, это скорее комментарий. Дополните и расширьте свой ответ.